# how do I give a limit to adding of certain item in a listview?

Tags: c#, listview

So I have 2 listviews in my Window Form Application in c#, `listview1` and `listview2`.  `listview1` is populated from a datatable and `listview2` is completely empty and not linked to anything.

When I double-click an item in listview1 it is copied to `listview2`.

I want to add a limit to the adding of that item.  For example, my `listview1` contains playing cards and it looks like...

```
listview1        listview2
itemname         itemname
Ace
King
Queen
Jack
```

The rule is that you can only have at most `4` of each entry from `listview1` in `listview2`.  So if I want `King` and `Queen` then `listview2` should accept at most `4` of each of those (but not all at once - one by one maybe you want `3` cards of `King` and `4` cards of `Queen`, the maximum limit should be `4` in that sense).

For example...

```
listview1        listView2
item name        item name
Ace              King
King             King
Queen            King
Jack             Queen
                 Queen
                 Queen
                 Queen
```

Can someone please help me with this?  What kind of condition do I apply?  How do I check if the selected item from `listview1` is already present `4` times in `listview2`?  How do I limit them to a certain number?

Thanks!
Still need help with this problem!

**Appendix**

I created a simple test project, here is the code for it

```
namespace Listviewtest 
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void listView1_ItemActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            copyCard(listView1, listView2);
        }

        private static void copyCard(ListView listView1, ListView listView2)
        {
            /* condition here to check if the selected item in listview1 is already present in listview2 and checking the count if its at 4 or not - I don't know the syntax for comparing */

            if()
            {
                foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.SelectedItems)
            {
                listView2.Items.Add((ListViewItem)item.Clone());
            }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You already have 4 of that card.");
            }
        }

        private void listView2_ItemActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listView2.SelectedItems[0].Remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the stackoveflow. There are very minimal chances to get ready made solution of your problem here. You need to share what code or solution approach you have tried so far to solve the problem. If you are facing any issue in the current code/approach people here will be happy to help you solving that issue. You also need to mention what kind of application it is. Windows Form or Web? ASP.NET WebForm or MVC?

Comment: The `listview` is only a data structure for rendering data. I would suggest you keep other data structures for your logic. Don't rely on the `listview` data capabilities. Store your objects in a `List` say, create functions according to your logic, and then bind the result to the listview.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thank you! and thank you for your reply but as to the solution approach, i am blank as to what is to be done for comparing items from 2 listview.

Comment: @Candide Thanks for the reply! its nothing complicated of that sorts i think, just want to add a limit on copying of an item from one listview to other

Answer (score 0):

add condition to `onclick` like this:

```
if(listview2.Items.Length!=limit)
{
   listview2.Items.Add(copyedItem);
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("Limit achieved!");
}
```

be care! it's pseudocode!

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I tried to use that condition, it doesnt work, theres no listview2.Items.Length in intellisense